# PHP array declaration breaking page

Tags: php, html

I have a baffling problem and a total blind spot as far as fixing it goes.

The below code produces this output:

```
"one", "test2" => "two", ); ?>
```

Why? I checked everything I can think of, tried an HTML validator, tried multiple browsers on multiple machines, tried two different servers, too. I can't find the syntax error. No error in the php log.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Test Query</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>

    <?php
      $serverName = "testsrv";      
      $connection_options = array("test" => "one", 
                                  "test2" => "two", );
    ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's not executing as PHP, and the browsers see the => as the close bracket for the <?php

Comment: What is the extension of the file? Unless the server is specifically configured to, it will not parse php in a `.html` file. Ensure that the file extension is `.php`

Comment: @landons - hmmm, you may be right. Good point on the => being somehow seen as the closing bracket for PHP ( though it should see ?> as that, shouldn't it? ) It's too weird, I have other pages on this server that behaves, but let me check everything one more time. I've been assuming that the php is being parsed correctly because putting a non-array declaration in there does not result in the code being printed ( for example, putting just the $serverName line in there doesn't print out ) but that assumption may be wrong.

Comment: @user2316154 - it's not being seen as the closing tag for PHP - it's the closing HTML tag. The server, for whatever reason, isn't interpreting the `<?php` tag as a PHP tag, just as a HTML one; so your client is seeing a tag it doesn't recognise, and assuming that the first `>` it sees is the closing tag.

Comment: @dleiftah - the extension is .htm. On the server there is another .htm file that embeds php code in the same manner ( the actual code is a bit long to paste in here, I will see if I can shorten it ) that works just fine. That is actually the file I copied a snippet from to start a new document, which started this whole surprise.

Comment: @ andrewsi - ah-hah. Yes, that seems to be what is happening, then. I tried a print statement in the php and yep, didn't execute. The part I can't get my head around just yet is *why*. On this exact same server, I have another page with php embedded that works. Somewhere I missed something, and I can't see where that somewhere is. But it must be in the server setup. This server is set up a little weirdly - it is PHP in IIS, and in this case the page that works is in a different site under IIS than the page that doesn't work. I thought the extension mapping was global ... am I horribly wrong?

Comment: @user2316154 - I'm afraid I don't know about IIS to be able to say, but I'd say you probably could restrict mappings to specific directories, though I wouldn't know where to start looking. You could always copy your test file to the known-working directory to see if it works there....

Comment: @andrewsi - I don't often use IIS either, and it tripped me up. You sure CAN restrict mappings, and the mappings were restricted ... oy. Hopefully I hit my head hard enough that I'd remember this for the inevitable next time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the server does not have PHP installed, is not configured correctly, or your file extension is wrong. In your browser, if you do View->Source, you'll see the full PHP code. The reason you only see part of it on the rendered view is because the browser treats the `<` and `>` within the code as HTML tags.

Comment: Here's the funny thing with that. This page is part of a larger site on the same server that uses php as well, and that piece works great. Same extension. Viewing page source in FireFox shows the full PHP code, and it turns the php code red like it should, up to just before that fifth quotation mark that starts the "one" - then it turns the code black like it is reading it as regular html.

Comment: you are right, of course, and I am embarrassed! Very silly mistake on my part - the server really didn't have PHP configured correctly. I missed that there wasn't a handler in IIS for the site this page was under. Adding that handler worked! I would still be pondering this problem if it wasn't for you guys. This is what happens when you try to work on 10 problems at once ... Well, I learned from my mistake, for sure!

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I see is possibly that last comma after "two"